# Matlab circle symbol has jagged edge with thicker linewidth

Tags: matlab, geometry

I ran into this problem that when I set the `linewidth` property of a series of circle symbols to 3 or larger, the edge of the circle appears very jagged, like shown below:
[image: thicker circle with jagged edges]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I saw a very [old post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.general/13274) that discussed a similar problem using the function `scatter`, but I can't get the recommended command to work, probably because it was a much older version of Matlab.

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: I would add: `x=0:0.01:pi; plot(x,sin(x),'LineWidth',10);`.

Comment: Still haven't figured out how to correct this. But I found out that if I used another laptop which runs Windows 8, the circles are plotted nicely without the jagged edges. The above figure was plotted using a machine running Windows 7. Would that be related to the hardware or something on the lower level?

Comment: It might. Anyway I'm using a mac.